# How do I find the first index of a string that occurs before a specified index in another string?

Tags: ruby, string, indexing

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  How do I find theh first index of a string that occurs before a particular index in another string?  That is, let's say I have this string

```
"ab cd ab cd ab cd ef"
```

And I want to find the first index of "ab" that occurs before index 10 in the above string.  The answer would be index 6 in this example.  If I want to find the index of "ab" that occurs before index 5 in teh above string, the answer would be zero.  I'm not sure how to use Ruby's "index" function to achieve what I want.

Comment: By "How do I find the first index of a string that occurs before a particular index?" do you main "For a given string, how do I find the largest index of the beginning of a substring such that the index does not exceed a specified value?" "another string" is confusing, as you don't give a second string in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str = "ab cd ab cd ab cd ef"

# find the first index of "ab", working backwards from index 10:
p str.rindex("ab", 10) # => 6
```

`rindex` being short for "reverse_index", I guess.